On the restriction of even/odd-parity representations of $O(3)$
Let $\text{Res}^{G}_{H}$ be the restriction from a representation of $G$ to that of $H\subseteq G$, and let $(\rho)^{H}$ denote the $H$-invariant subspace of $\rho$, the representation of $G$. I am interested in the particular calculation:
$$\left(\text{Res}^{O(d)}_{O(d+2-m)}\bigotimes_{i=1}^{n}\rho_{i}\right)^{O(d+2-m)},$$
which computes the number of tensor structures, and where $m = \text{min}(n,d+2)$. For the cases of $(n,d) = (3,3)$ and $(n,d) = (4,3)$, we have $m = 3$. Let us denote parity even/odd spin-$\ell$ representations of $O(3)$ by $\ell^{\pm}$. The spin-$\ell$ representation of $O(2)$ are denoted by $\ell$ and the scalars/pseudoscalars are denoted by $0^{\pm}$. Also, let us denote the parity even/odd representations of $O(1)$ as $\cdot^{\pm}$.
I want to understand how to compute explicit expressions for $\left(\text{Res}^{O(3)}_{O(2)}\ell^{\pm}\right)^{\otimes 3}$ and $\left(\text{Res}^{O(3)}_{O(2)}\ell^{\pm}\right)^{\otimes 4}$, for the cases of $\ell = 1,2$.
